# Using InstallCommandSetsFromFileAsync from Isolated Storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am currently speech-enabling my app in Windows Phone 8 by using the VoiceCommandService.InstallCommandSetsFromFileAsync method to install grammar definitions from an XML file.

Using this function, is it possible to load the commands via the isolated storage instead somehow? The idea is that I want to make the commands editable, so that the user can add new commands on his own which will be implemented the next time the application launches.

Currently I am doing this:

```
await VoiceCommandService.InstallCommandSetsFromFileAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Commands.xml"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out I just had to refer to it by writing `ms-appdata:///local/Commands.xml` instead of `ms-appx:///Commands.xml` to load it dynamically.

It was done through guessing and past experiences with similar resources. Pretty weird that there was no documentation on this.